# How to split training and test sets?

Tags: python, split

Where should we use

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test= train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

and where should we use

```
train, test= train_test_split(data, test_size=0.3, random_state=0).
```

The former one return this:

> value error: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

Answer (score 1):

The first form you use if you want to split instances with features (X) and labels (y). The second form you use if you only want to split features (X).

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(data, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

The reason why it didn' t work for you was because you didn't prodide the label data in your `train_test_split()` function. The above should work well. Just replace `y` with your label/target data.

Answer (score 1):

`train_test_split` method accepts as many arrays as argument as you need.

But, since you need *four* returned values you have to pass `2` arrays as *argument*.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(data, y_data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
```

If you need to pass many arrays you can use ***extended iterable unpacking*** operator.

```
train_test_split(*arrays, test_size = test_size, random_state = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have 1 data list, it split to 2,

```
                             |---data_train
data ----train_test_split()--|
                             |---data_test
```

if you have 2 data list, it split **EACH** of the data list to 2, that is 4 in total.

```
                                       |---data_train_x
                                       |---data_train_y
data_x, data_y ----train_test_split()--|
                                       |---data_test_x
                                       |---data_test_y
```

The same as *n* data list.